# Como saber sin un "remove" en mi controlador fue rechazado a causa de una violación de llave foránea?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc, try-catch

como decirle al usuario que un registro no se ha eliminado debido a que tiene  otras entidades a las que hereda su llave primaria por medio de try/catch?

```
try
{
    db.usuarios.Remove(usuario);
}
catch(?????)
{
    ???????
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sino tienes habilitada la eliminacion en cascada deberia controlar el exception usando algo como ser

```
try
{
    db.usuarios.Remove(usuario);
}
catch (DbUpdateException ex)
{
    var sqlException = ex.GetBaseException() as SqlException;

    if (sqlException != null)
    {

    }
}
```

[Cannot catch SqlException in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25936614/cannot-catch-sqlexception-in-entity-framework)

al obtener el exception de sql podrias recorrer los errores y validar el `Number` para determinar si hay alguno relacionado con `Foreign Key violation`